# ElasticSearch return not maximum ID when i'm searching by descending id

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index URI

```
contracts/_doc/
```

I push my documents there, ID is pre-generated by SQL-DB

this is the code sample from JAVA client:

```
    final BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();
    contracts.forEach(e -> request.add(new IndexRequest(CONTRACT_INDEX,
                                                        CONTRACT_INDEX_TYPE,
                                                        String.valueOf(e.getId()))
                                            .source("contractNumber", e.getContractNumber())
                                        )
    );
```

Sometimes i need to see the biggest value of ID in my index, and i send this query

```
{
    "sort" : [
        { "_id" : {"order" : "desc"}}
    ],
    "size": 1
}
```

The problem is that ElasticSearch always return value no more than `9999`

```
        "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "contracts",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "9999",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "contractNumber": "2000/290/990990"
            },
            "sort": [
                "9999"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

When i'm performing search with query:

```
{
"size": 10000
```

}

the actual result is in proper state, all my ID's over 9999 is present and select by

```
contracts/_doc/10005
```

returns proper result.

Please advise how i can solve this situation

Comment: The reason is that your IDs are strings and strings are sorted lexicographically, not numerically, hence in the string world 9999 > 1000000. What you should do is to have another numerical field in your document that contains the numeric equivalent of your ID field and sort by that numeric field

Comment: @Val yes, your advice work well, thanks. Post your answer and i'll approve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your IDs are strings and strings are sorted lexicographically, not numerically, hence in the string world 9999 > 1000000.

What you should do is to have another numerical field in your document that contains the numeric equivalent of your ID field and sort by that numeric field.