# Elastic 6.3 sorting not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

The below query should return all documents which have user-region as germany and should be sorted on the user-id field. However the sorting doesn't work correctly. It should start with user-id 2 however it starts with 10 and 2 is in the middle somewhere.

Mapping type of user-region is keyword and user-id is keyword (user-id can be a string just used integers here for brevity).

Can anyone please point out what is wrong with the query.

Query :

```
{
    "size" : 10,
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "user-region" : "germany"}
            }
        }
    },
  "sort": [
    {
      "user-id": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}


{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 20,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "10",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "10",
                    "user-region": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "10"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "12",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "12",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "12"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "14",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "14",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "14"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "16",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "16",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "16"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "18",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "18",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "18"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "2",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "20",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "20",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "20"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "22",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "22",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "22"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "24",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "24",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "24"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "user",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "26",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "is-admin": false,
                    "docType": ":cm:user",
                    "user-id": "26",
                    "oem-id": "germany",

                    "version": "1.0"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "26"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a bug ;-) Here is the reason why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836819/elasticsearch-return-not-maximum-id-when-im-searching-by-descending-id/51837464#51837464

Comment: Jeez, sorts lexicographically ofcourse. :-D. Thanks man.