# Elastic Search Sorting -

Tags: elasticsearch

My Data looks like this  After sorting  : Below is the response after sorting. But this is not the expected output.

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 8,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVTy-v9pbhY5QtJPGe",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "5"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "5"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVTmY89pbhY5QtJPGa",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "3"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVTxXe9pbhY5QtJPGd",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "100"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "100"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVTpYJ9pbhY5QtJPGc",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "10-"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "10-"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVTk1x9pbhY5QtJPGY",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "1-7"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "1-7"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVTnsm9pbhY5QtJPGb",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "1-6"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "1-6"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVTjAq9pbhY5QtJPGX",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "1-2"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "1-2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "size",
                "_id": "AWVVThkT9pbhY5QtJPGW",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "e_size": "1"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Below is the sort used to get the results.

```
 {
     "sort": [{
         "e_size": {
             "order": "desc"

         }
     }]
 }
```

e_size type is "String" and index is "not_analyzed"

How to fix this sort issue. Do we need to use any analyzer for this. Or e_size data type should be different.

Comment: Here is the reason why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836819/elasticsearch-return-not-maximum-id-when-im-searching-by-descending-id/51837464#51837464

Answer (score 0):

It has sorted it correctly. You can try to sort those strings yourself and you would get the same result.

Example:
`["100", "10-"]`

here `"0" < "-"` so that's why `"10-"` comes after `"100"` and so on. you can think of it as how do you find some words in a dictionary.

Either make `e_size` a number or use any different series of string for each e_size

Comment: I am using elasticsearch version 1.5

Comment: if "1-2" is a range, then why don't you store it as min and max values saperately as Numbers ? If its not a range, and you want to store it as a string then you should know that "101" will be greater than "2" when you compare their first digits. Then make sure threy have different initial values